# How to get Operating System Name in WiX Installer in non windows Operating Systems?

Tags: linux, wix, windows-installer, wine, wix3.7

Recently I learned that we can execute a MSI file prepared for Windows operating system in Linux using **Wine**.

For our software we checked few pre-requisites like the Operating system should be Windows XP or higher using windows installer variable **VersionNT**.

But there is no such variable available where I can check if it is windows OR Linux. My requirement is if it is Linux I want to check some other set of per-requisites.

Is there a way I can get the operating system name in WiX?

Comment: Why downvote after so many days? Moderators should look at this. Without reason a downvote should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't begin to say which properties get set in this reverse engineered environment.  I'd suggest logging your install (typically /l*v but may be different ) and then see what properties it reports as being set and see if one of those meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Will check with `msiexec/i [MSI file] /l*v InstallLog.log` if that helps.